# (haskell) stack init does not finish. how to ignore all bounds in existing cabal files?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

I am converting a project (consisting of several cabalized packages) to stack. "stack init" does not seem to be able to "calculate a build plan" (it takes ages).

Perhaps this gets easier when all version bounds are ignored. But how can I do this - other than actually removing them from the cabal files manually?

EDIT: there is "allow-newer" in http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/ but this only helps if the initial stack.yaml file is already there.

Anyway, I could work around my particular problem by manually removing some packages (that is, subdirs) to be built.

My actual comand line was

```
stack init --verbose --resolver=lts-5   $(cat DIRS) --solver
```

Comment: Do you use `--solver`? IIRC `stack init` only tries snapshots in some order without it, so it should finish quite fast if there is snapshot with all needed dependencies

Comment: `--solver`: yes, see edit above.

Comment: There really isn't much value in keeping upper bounds on your dependencies when you're using stack unless there's a specific compatibility problem that you need to handle. For publishing your package you can always use `stack sdist --pvp-bounds upper` and let stack add the upper bounds.

Comment: You might be interested in this blog post on the `pvp-bounds` feature: https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2015/09/stack-pvp